# cakephp ajax helper issue

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-ui-accordion

I am currently using the ajax helper found at http://www.cakephp.bee.pl/

I have accordion i would like to update using $this->ajax

here is code for the ajax form submit button

```
    <?php echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array(

'url'=> array(
'controller'=>'qnotes', 
'action'=>'add'
 ),

 'update'=>'divleft',
 'position'=>'html',
 'before'=>'$("accordion").accordion("disable");alert("before");',
 'after'=>'$("#accordion").accordion("destroy").accordion({autoHeight: false, collapsible: false , active: false, header: "h3"});alert(response.requestText)',
'complete'=>'$("#accordion").accordion("destroy").accordion({autoHeight: false, collapsible: false , active: false, header: "h3"});',
 'success'=>'$("#dialog1").dialog("close");'

    ));  
?>
```

here the format of the accordion

```
<div id="divleft">
 <div id="accordion">
  <h3><a href ></h3>
  <ul>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>itejm 3</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

The Issue.

Cannot update the accordion with out losing the accordion functionality and if the accordion updates it loses its accordion styling.

Is there something wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to ask is how do you create the accordion element? Do you use the AjaxHelper class or simply the jQuery method?

After you submit the form, you are using jQuery UI syntax to destroy and recreate new accordion. But to create it using the Helper, you would have to use the $ajax object and it's functions. Is there a way, that AjaxHelper changes the UI definition and wraps it somehow?

Comment: To create the Accordion I use the the normal Jquery Method.